# "File not found" while using GitHub Action

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have created [this GitHub action](https://github.com/matheusjardimb/exact-dependency-checker-action) and published into the [GH Actions Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/exact-dependency-checker), but I'm having problems while trying to use it in another of my projects.

I've created [this PR](https://github.com/matheusjardimb/git_tips_and_tricks/pull/13/files) which adds the Action to the CI workflow, but I keep getting the same error bellow:

[image]

```
Run matheusjardimb/exact-dependency-checker-action@v0.8.1
  with:
    packageJsonPath: package.json
Error: File not found: '/home/runner/work/_actions/matheusjardimb/exact-dependency-checker-action/v0.8.1/dist/main.js'
```

What am I missing? I cloned the repo again locally and the file `exact-dependency-checker-action/dist/main.js` do exists (without the `v0.8.1/` into the path). Why was the version added to the path? Can this be the reason for the error?